# Find surface edge from signed distance function & derivative

Tags: geometry

I have a signed distance function that describes a mesh in **3D space**. I have a few points given in space that mark the exact location of a sign change. Additionally, to each of those points I have the normal vector of the function at that point. 
Now my question is: it possible with the given data (& if so how) to calculate the underlying surface edge ?
What I am basically looking for is nothing but a directional vector. The problem is really easy to solve in 2D. Since I have the normal, all I gotta do is to calculate a vector that is perpendicular to that normal. 
But there's an infinite amount of perpendicular vectors to a vector in 3D, so that doesn't seem to work here...

Here is a visualtion of what I might have. In 2D just to keep it simple. Again, I am looking for a solution in 3D space.

Example image: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you do need an additional vector. It can be global, one single vector that is used for all points.

Let's say you have point $\vec{p}_i$ on the surface, $\vec{n}_i$ is the normal vector at that point, and $\vec{a}$ is your global direction vector.

For each point $\vec{p}_i$ on the surface, you want to find the two tangent vectors $\vec{u}_i$ and $\vec{v}_i$. We can do this by picking $\vec{u}_i$ as perpendicular to normal $\vec{n}_i$ and $\vec{a}$, and $\vec{v}_i$ as perpendicular to normal $\vec{n}_i$ and $\vec{u}_i$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{u}_i &= \vec{n}_i \times \vec{a} \\
\vec{v}_i &= \vec{n}_i \times \vec{u}_i \\
\end{aligned}$$

Unfortunately, this breaks down in the case where the normal $\vec{n}_i$ is parallel to $\vec{a}$ ($\vec{n}_i \parallel \vec{a}$): then, $\vec{u}_i = \vec{u}_i = 0$. This is trivial to solve, however, since you can simply choose $\vec{u}_i$ and $\vec{v}_i$ to be any vector pair perpendicular to each other and $\vec{a}$.)

If we consider a sphere, and pick $\vec{a}$ from pole to pole, then $\vec{u}_i$ are along latitudes, and $\vec{v}_i$ longitudes.

---

Note that if the surface is a polygon mesh (say, a triangle mesh), this will not find the edges of the surface. To do that, you find the discontinuities in the normal vector: at an edge or vertex, the normal vector changes discontinuously.

Comment: I don't understand how to choose the a vector. Does that vector need to have any relation to the surface ? How do I choose this vector ?
Also, what do I do with those 2 resulting tangent vectors ? I am only looking one 1 vector.

Comment: @PAThePianoDude: In 3D, a tangent to a surface is a plane. You can describe it with a normal vector, or two tangent vectors. All three are orthogonal (perpendicular to each other). If you ignore lengths, any two suffice, because the third is their cross product. What you are asking for makes no sense, unless there is an underlying problem you want to solve, but have not described yet. Care to edit your question, to describe what you intend to achieve with this? What problem does it solve?